# Generar un "var" desde JavaScript llamando a un Objeto Java

Tags: javascript, java, google-maps, object, objeto

Quisiera poder generar un "var" desde JavaScript mediante una llamada a Java.

Tengo un código en JS y un Objeto Java con los siguientes atributos

```html
<script>
          ...

            var almeria = [
              { lng: -3.94529509544373,lat:40.4549980163575 },
              { lng: -3.93923902511591,lat:40.4606246948243 },
              { lng: -3.93966102600098,lat:40.4653930664064 },
              { lng: -3.93692398071289,lat:40.4679946899415 }
              ...
            ]; 

            var polyShape = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths:almeria, 
              ...
            });

            polyShape.setMap(map);
            
          ...
</script>

public class Region {
      private String nombre;
      private List<Coordenada> Coordenadas;
}
```

Ahora bien, ¿cómo podría hacer una llamada a una función que generase la variable en JS con los atributos del objeto java? ¿cómo sería ella función?
Quería setear tanto el nombre de la variable como su cuerpo ¿cuál sería la forma más fácil de hacerlo, si es posible?

Un saludo y muchas gracias. Si hay algo que no haya explicado bien, preguntad.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript es un lenguaje del entorno cliente y Java es un lenguaje del entorno del servidor, por lo tanto, tienes que establecer una comunicación vía http, es decir, una petición, obviamente necesitas todo el entorno servidor de java, por ejemplo usando Springboot.

Para este caso en concreto, usa "Ajax", te permitirá lanzar una petición al servidor y recoger los datos en el javascript.

Te pongo un ejemplo con **AngularJS**.

```
// te declaras tu var en js
    var datos = {
       "nombre": null,
       "coordenadas": null
    };
    // creas y lanzas la petición
    var req = {
            method: 'GET',
            url: url de tu servicio,
            headers: {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                }
            };
    $http(req).then(
            // Ha ido bien y metes los datos de la respuesta http a tu objeto.
            function (response) {
                datos.nombre  = response.nombre;
                datos.coordenadas = response.Coordenadas;
             })}
```

También tienes ejemplos en google para Jquery, para Javascript (con XMLHttpRequest) etc...

Si lo vas a desarrollar en tu local, tendrás que deshabilitar los cors en tu servidor, o sino, modifica tu "google chrome o firefox" o el navegador que uses con "Click derecho en propiedades y en destino pones:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\chrome.exe" --user-data-dir="C://Chrome dev session" --disable-web-security
```

Para saltarse la seguridad de los cors en localhost.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la repuesta. Justo eso quería saber. Un saludo.

Comment: dale flecha arriba y un verde, eso me ayudaría a mí :P